# Find the modulus of $\exp\{iR^2\cos (2t) - R^2 \sin (2t)\}$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

How do I find the modulus of $|\exp\{iR^2\cos (2t) - R^2 \sin (2t)\}|$?

Wouldn't it be the same as absolute value of the thing inside?

Comment: do you know that $\Big|e^{ix}\Big| = 1$?

Comment: Yes it would.  But the point of the problem is for you to notice that the imaginary part of the term in the exponent does not affect the modulus.

Comment: @echzhen thanks for the hint, I managed to figure it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Assuming $t$  is real,

$$e^{-R^2\sin2t}\cdot e^{i(R^2\cos2t)}$$

Now use $|xy|=|x||y|$ and Euler's identity to find $|e^{i(R^2\cos2t)}|=1$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** -

Write it as $\dfrac{\exp\{iR^2\cos(2t)\}}{\exp\{R^2\sin(2t)\}}$ and recall that $\left|\dfrac{z_1}{z_2}\right|=\dfrac{|z_1|}{|z_2|}$ and $|\exp\{it\}|=1$

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that $R$ and $t$ are real numbers, so we have:
$$
\left| \exp\{iR^2\cos (2t) - R^2 \sin (2t)\} \right|=\exp\{- R^2 \sin (2t)\}\exp\{iR^2\cos (2t)\}
$$
and , since $|e^{i\theta}|=1 \quad \forall \theta \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
\left| \exp\{iR^2\cos (2t) - R^2 \sin (2t)\} \right|=\exp\{- R^2 \sin (2t)\}
$$

Answer (score 1):

let $w=e^{i\theta}$, where $\theta=R^2(\cos(2t)-iR^2(\sin(2t))=R^2e^{-i2t}$.  Letting $z^2=(Re^{-it})^2$, you just need to find $|w|$

$$|w|=|e^{-iz^2}|=1$$